# Insert the same distinct list twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can insert a list of distinct values from an existing table into another existing table:

```
insert into [MyDb]..[User]
([UserName])
(Select distinct [PersonName]
from [Server].[Db].[dbo].[People]
where [Person] != 'Unknown')
```

Where the inner select statement brings back `Jim,Jon,Joe`
So the table looks like:

```
UserName | DisplayName
----------------------
  Jim    |   NULL
  Jon    |   NULL
  Joe    |   NULL
```

But I want to put this same list in another column in the `[User]` table, something like:

```
insert into [MyDb]..[User]
([UserName],[DisplayName])
    values (
(Select distinct [PersonName]
from [Server].[Db].[dbo].[People]
where [Person] != 'Unknown')
    ,
(Select distinct [PersonName]
from [Server].[Db].[dbo].[People]
where [Person] != 'Unknown')
    )
```

So the final table looks like:

```
UserName | DisplayName
----------------------
  Jim    |    Jim
  Jon    |    Jon
  Joe    |    Joe
```

Selecting two distinct lists like this doesn't work. I tried giving the inner select statement an alias which didn't work. I think I can do this easily in two separate statements but I'm wondering if there's syntax to make `[DisplayName] = [UserName]` during the insert list statement...

**Is it possible to do this in one transaction?**

Comment: Don't use "Unknown" values, use _null_.

Comment: Don't have a choice. Not my database. This is an exercise to migrate data over where there's no such entry as `unknown`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the column twice:

```
insert into [MyDb]..[User]([UserName], DisplayName)
Select distinct [PersonName], [PersonName]
from [Server].[Db].[dbo].[People]
where [Person] != 'Unknown'
```